# SQL - How to DELETE a row using AVG() data from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

I need to delete students from `students` table, who have an average mark that is not higher than 3,5.

Marks are stored in the `exax_marks` table, which has a column `student_id` in it.
Students are stored in the `students` table, which can be joined to `exam_marks` by `id`.

Here's the query I wrote and it doesn't work:

```
DELETE s FROM students AS s
JOIN exam_marks AS em ON s.id. = em.student_id
WHERE em.AVG(mark) <= 3.5
```

Here's another query I tried that didn't work either:

```
DELETE s FROM students s
JOIN exam_marks em ON s.id. = em.student_id
WHERE s.id IN(
SELECT student_id FROM exam_marks 
GROUP BY student_id 
HAVING AVG(mark) <= 3.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE s
    FROM students s
    WHERE (SELECT AVG(em.mark)
           FROM exam_marks em
           WHERE s.id = em.student_id
          ) <= 3.5;
```

That said, this is a ridiculous thing to do, unless you have cascading foreign key constraints.  If not, you will have student ids in `exam_marks` that are "dangling" -- they don't refer to anything.  Or if the foreign key is declared, you may not be able to do the delete at all.

Comment: I think you're right and I will have to delete from both tables. Any ideas of a query in that situation?

Comment: @YuriiParfinenko . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  You should ask *new* questions as a **new** question.